# If every real-valued continuous bounded function on a metric space $M$ attains its maximum (or minimum), then $M$ is compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Suppose that $(M,d)$ is a metric space. I want to show if every continuous bounded  function $f:M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ achieves a maximum or minimum, them $M$ is compact.

I found a similar assertion in the question [If every real-valued continuous function is bounded on $X$ (metric space), then $X$ is compact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668905/if-every-real-valued-continuous-function-is-bounded-on-x-metric-space-then) The trick of proof of that assertion is to assume that $M$ is not compact and then make an unbounded function, but here the function must be bounded. What should I do?

Comment: $$t \mapsto \frac{t}{1+\lvert t\rvert}$$

Comment: @DanielFischer so why this function doesn't get its extremum?

Comment: That function is not defined on $M$, but on $\mathbb{R}$. But you can use it to get a bounded function that doesn't attain its maximum (or minimum) if you have an unbounded function on $M$. You can of course also directly modify the construction.