# What is the relation between compactness , connectedness and continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R^n}$, n > 1?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What is the relation between compactness, connectedness and continuous real-valued functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$, n > 1?

For example,
1- what is the relation between a compact set and boundedness of every continuous real valued function on it?

2- If a set on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact, is it bounded? and if it is bounded is it compact?

Comment: All this in the real line or something else?..your question lacks some context..you have to be more clear

Comment: Do you mean theorems relating the various concepts? Well it's not hard to prove that the continuous image of compact spaces are compact and continuous image of connected spaces are connected.

Comment: On $\mathbb{R^n}$ @MariosGretsas

Comment: then see the comment of @JohnGriffin

Comment: I mean what is the relation between a compact set and boundedness of every continuous real valued function on it, for example @JohnGriffin

Comment: @Intuition I've added an answer addressing this question. Please edit your post to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Ok I have done .... thank u @JohnGriffin

Comment: Every continuous function on A being bounded = A being compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is compact and $f:X\to\mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous. Then $f$ is bounded.

*Proof:*
Since the continuous image of compact spaces are compact, we know that $f(X)$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Thus it is a bounded subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the Heine-Borel theorem.

The Heine-Borel theorem mentioned above says:

> A subset $E$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact iff $E$ is closed and bounded.

Thus compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ are bounded. However, the converse is not true. For instance, $(0,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ is bounded but not compact.

Comment: Is it true that "If every continuous real valued function defined on a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$", n>1, is bounded, then this non empty subset is compact?

Comment: @Intuition Yes.

Comment: why ? ..... is there a theorem that said this?

Comment: I have a problem ..... your answer contains half of the answer of the question and @Marios Gretsas contains the other half ..... so I do not know who to accept?

Comment: @Intuition accept whatever you want..accept the answer that you believe it helps you the most..Don't worry.. If you accept John's answer,which of course is a nice answer,there would be no problem by me.

Comment: @Intuition See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668905/if-every-real-valued-continuous-function-is-bounded-on-x-metric-space-then

Answer (score 1):

A continuous image of a connected set is connected.

Also a topological space $X$ is connected iff there does not exist a surjective continuous function from $X$ to $\{0,1\}$(or any set with two elements in the reals for instance).

Now for compactness-continuity  we have also these results:

> If $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous bijection and $X$ ia compact topological space and $Y$ is a Hausdorf topological space then $f$ is a homeomorphism.

.

> Every continuous function on a compact metric space $X$ is uniformly continuous on $X$

Comment: can I say that if a subset of $\mathbb{R^n}$, where n > 1, is compact then its connected?

Comment: No because the set $([0,1] \times [0,1]) \cup( [5,6] \times [5,6])$ is compact but not connected..Note that a finite union of compact sets is compact.

Comment: I have a problem ..... your answer contains half of the answer of the question and @John Griffin contains the other half ..... so I do not know who to accept?