# Does every non-compact Tychonoff space admit an unbounded continuous function?

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a completely regular Hausdorff space. Such a space is also known as [Tychonoff space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tychonoff_space), or a $T_{3.5}$-space. Furthermore, let's assume that $X$ is not compact.

**Question.** Does $X$ admit a continuous function $f: X\to \mathbb{R}$ with unbounded image?

**Context.** It is known that if $X$ is a non-compact metric space, then $X$ admits an unbounded continuous real-valued function. This was discussed thoroughly in [this MSE thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/668905/49227). Note that the same conclusion holds if $X$ is a non-compact normal space (also known as $T_4$-space).  This is because the proof using Tietze extension theorem (see the answer in the linked MSE thread by the user **Espace' etale**) still works. This is the motivation for asking the current question.

In general, Tietze extension theorem fails for $T_{3.5}$-spaces (for example, consider [the Moore plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore_plane)), so one cannot apply the trick above; of course, it is possible that the question has a negative answer, in which case I'd love to see a counter-example.

Comment: The linked question does not specifically ask for Tychonoff spaces but several of the examples in the answers are Tychonoff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not necessarily. A space $X$ such that every continuous $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is bounded is called [*pseudocompact*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocompact_space). Every countably compact space is pseudocompact, and $\omega_1$ with the order topology is a countably compact, non-compact Tikhonov (and even hereditarily normal) space, so it is also a pseudocompact space that is not compact. (Note that the argument by **Espace' etale** uses more than normality: it also uses the fact that sequential compactness implies compactness in metric spaces.)