# Proving $K$ is compact directly.

Tags: real-analysis

> If $K$ is a subset of metric space $\mathbb{R}^n$ and if every real valued continuous function on $K$ is bounded,  then $K$ is compact.

I know a proof considering $K$ is unbounded and not closed. This is proof by contradiction.

> Is there any direct way to prove?

Please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If every real-valued continuous function is bounded on $X$ (metric space), then $X$ is compact.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668905/if-every-real-valued-continuous-function-is-bounded-on-x-metric-space-then)

Comment: Yes! But is there any direct way where we can show for any open cover of $K$ there exists a finite subcover?

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $U_n$ is a sequence of open sets that cover $(X,d)$.  Let
$$ f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^{-n} \min\{d(x,U_n^C),1\} .$$
We know $f(x) > 0$ for $x \in X$.  So by hypothesis, $1/f$ is bounded above by $2^{N-1}$ for some $N \in \mathbb N$.  Hence $f(x) > 2^{-N}$ for all $x\in X$, and so $X \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^N U_n$.

This shows every countable cover has a finite subcover.

Not sure how to complete it.

Comment: It seems that your $N$ depends on $x$? And it's not clear how the assumptions on the space of continuous functions are used.

Comment: No it doesn't.  Changed my answer to make that clearer.

Comment: Can you please clarify how $f > 2^{-N}$ implies that $X \subset U_1\cup\cdots \cup U_N$?

Comment: Because if $x \not\in U_1 \cup \cdots \cup U_N$, then $f(x) \le \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty 2^{-n}$.