# Suppose that if $A$ is not compact in metric space, then $\exists \delta>0$ and closed balls $B_n$ in $A$, s.t. $d(B_n, B_m)>\delta, n\not=m$.

Tags: functional-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

When I was reading a textbook about functional analysis, I notice a theorem:

> In metric space, if every continuous functions on a closed set $A$ is bounded, then $A$ must be compact.

In the proof, it says that

> Suppose that if $A$ is not compact in metric space, then $\exists \delta>0$ and closed balls $B_n$ in $A$, s.t. $d(B_n, B_m)>\delta, n\not=m$.

My question is how to prove the existence of $B_n$?
I have tried the similar method in Hausdorff theorem about completely bounded set, but I couldn’t prove that the distances between $B_n$ have a positive bound below.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the sets $B_n$? In any metric space with more than one point, there exists $\delta>0$ and two sets $B_n$, $B_m$ with $d(B_n,B_m)>\delta$

Comment: @pancini sorry, I didn't express clearly. What I confused about is just the existence of $B_n$.

Comment: Cover $A$ with all possible balls. If these balls $B_n$ don't exist then you can find a finite subcover for $A$. Can you see why?

Comment: What about $A=X=\{1/n: n\in\mathbb N\}$ endowed with distance from $\mathbb R$?

Comment: The property that all continuous functions are bounded is called **pseudocompactness** and pseudocompact metric spaces are indeed compact.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks for reminding me of this concept. I have read some references mentioned in [Pseudocompact’s wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocompact_space) but I couldn’t find the proof.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Sorry, I didn’t know the reason.  And what do you mean by “all balls”? All the open balls in the whole metric space $X$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668905 contains a few proofs.

Comment: @Jochen Thanks, I have read about this question 668905, and I know the main goal is the same. But my question is just the detail of the method I mentioned.